# Recursive function and comment trees

Tags: android, recursion, view

I am using the reddit API and trying to load the comment tree of a thread. My problem is that I am using a recursive function to do that. I am building a view and then adding it programmatically. And it works for small threads but when it has to load a large comment tree I get stackoverflow.So my main question is: what is a good way to load nested comments programmatically and what is the best practice to go around the stack overflow? I have debated adding a counter for comments added and when they exceed some number I might break the loop, but that still doesn't guarantee me a "stackoverflow" free program. Generally speaking how can I keep track of the stack and the heap? Also as a follow up question: my dynamic view gets destroyed on rotation and I recreate it every time. The problem with that is recreating is slow and it slows the rotation. So is there an easy way to keep/save the view on rotation and add it again (setRetainInstance(true) has no effect on the dynamic view, just on the main layout).

```
private void addTextTree(JSONObject j, LinearLayout layoutparent) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject j2 = j.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray j3 = j2.getJSONArray("children");
    LinearLayout currentparent = layoutparent;
    Log.d("ADDINGVIEW", j3.length() + "");
    for (int i = 0; i < j3.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject j4 = j3.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject j5 = j4.getJSONObject("data");
        addComment(j5, currentparent);
    }
}

private void addComment(JSONObject j, LinearLayout parent) throws JSONException {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LinearLayout LLHmain = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LinearLayout LLVsecond = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

    LLHmain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LLHmain.setLayoutParams(lp);
    LLVsecond.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LLVsecond.setLayoutParams(lp1);

    TextView author = new TextView(getActivity());
    TextView content = new TextView(getActivity());

    ImageView bar = new ImageView(getActivity());
    bar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lines);
    LLHmain.addView(bar, lp1);

    author.setText(" " + j.optString("author") + "   " + j.optInt("score") + " points");
    author.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    String temp = j.optString("body_html");
    String temp1 = Html.fromHtml(temp.substring(22, temp.length() - 12)).toString();
    content.setText(Html.fromHtml(temp1));
    content.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    LLVsecond.addView(author, lp);
    LLVsecond.addView(content, lp);
    LLHmain.addView(LLVsecond, lp1);
    parent.addView(LLHmain, lp);
    if (!j.optString("replies").equals("")) {
        JSONObject replies = j.getJSONObject("replies");
        addTextTree(replies, LLVsecond);
    }
}
```

Summed up:

1. What is the best way to handle loading trees of textviews and preventing stack overflow.
2. Keeping track of the stack and the heap
3. Saving dynamic view on rotation

Disclaimer: I am new to any sort of programming and by no means do I believe this is the best or only way to do it. I am open to any possible solutions regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the very short version of the answer (because I'm kinda busy at work) but you follow it that you'll get what you want:

The issue is that `View` are memory heavy objects and shouldn't be allocating that many. What you do to avoid that is using a `ListView` that can recycle views.

So instead of recursively create and add views you'll create a data class, for example:

```
public class DataItem{
  String author;
  String content;
}
```

then you build an `ArrayList<DataItem>` and recursively add all the items to this array. Then you use this array in an `adapter` in the `listview`.

that way you can have a thread with thousands of items without issue.

Comment: Does your suggestion look something like [this very crappy drawing](http://i.imgur.com/OHckIxf.png?1?2602) ? I have used listfragment/listview but there wasn't any nesting so I'm not exactly sure how to wrap my head around it. Is the picture resembling what you have in mind ?